# Can't unregistering Broadcast Receiver in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that I try to unregister in the `OnPause()` method. But then it gets blocked it seems, and although I register it in the `OnResume()`, it doesn't fire. If I only register it it works well, but then I get the exception "leaking broadcast receiver, you should unregister it", as below:

```
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188): Activity com.example.android.CView has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.android.CView$1@4062b650 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.android.CView has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.android.CVieww$1@4062b650 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:790)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:575)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:848)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:835)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:829)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at cActivity com.example.android.BehaviourView.onStart(BehaviourView.java:230)
06-04 22:50:04.267: ERROR/ActivityThread(4188):     at
```

There are tons of posts concerning this, and I have tried many of them without results. The practice is to register it in `OnResume` and unregister it in the `OnPause`, right? Or should I unregister it in `onStop()`. I have tried and then it never listens.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The practice is to register it in OnResume and unregister it in the OnPause, right?

Yes. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/OnBattery) demonstrating this.

Comment: i tried your sample link and have done in same way but still i m getting error in onPause that error link http://pastie.org/9825190  my code is http://pastie.org/9825223

Comment: @user3233280: I have no idea why you would be getting that error.

Comment: any good tutorial for updating UI from Service as soon as ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED broadcast reciver calls ?

Comment: @user3233280: I have not used `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`.